# NSClassFromString using a Swift File

Tags: swift, objective-c-runtime, objective-c-swift-bridge

I have written a class in Swift in my existing Objective-C project. So far, the bridging has worked very well. I do have a method however, where I generate a class at runtime using NSClassFromString(). When the string is my Swift class name, it returns nil.

```
class MySwiftClass : NSObject {}
```

and in Objective-C:

```
Class myClass = NSClassFromString(@"MySwiftClass");
```

and myClass would be nil every time. I've also tried:

```
Class myClass = NSClassFromString(@"MyAppName.MySwiftClass");
```

and still nil.

Comment: Have you tried going the other way and seeing what `NSStringFromClass` has to say about MySwiftClass?

Comment: @CodaFi `NSStringFromClass` worked.

Answer (score 15):

All swift classes use the Product Module Name a dot and the classname for their namespace (Module.Class).  If you wanted to use "MySwiftClass" name for the class within your Objective-C code; you can add `@objc(MySwiftClass)` annotation to expose the same swift class name (without the module):

```
@objc(MySwiftClass)
class MySwiftClass{
    ...
}
```

Then

```
Class myClass = NSClassFromString(@"MySwiftClass");
```

Will contain the class instead of being nil.

Comment: This isn't working for some reason in my project, any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

A way to compatible Objective-C and Swift:

```
CQBaseViewController *detailVC = [[NSClassFromString(controller_name) alloc] init];

// if nil,check as Swift file
if (!detailVC) {
    NSString *prefix = [[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary][@"CFBundleExecutable"];
    NSString *swiftClassName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@", prefix, controller_name];
    detailVC = [[NSClassFromString(swiftClassName) alloc] init];
}
```